# How can files.list with pagination be combined with batch?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I have a gapi(v2) batch request for files in folder 'x'. This folder may have paginated list of contents.

I have tried recursively calling the files.list api(as shown in the gapi v2 docs) with the pageToken value set to the nextPageToken but that returns "Invalid Token".

```
var batch = gapi.client.newBatch();
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list();
batch.add(request, {'id': 'mySearch');

batch.then(handleResponse);

function handleResponse(resp) {
    // gets the first set of 100 files fine
    console.log(resp.result['mySearch'].result.items); // prints array of 100

    // handle nextPageToken here <- this is what I want to do
}
```

I need the array of all, say 435, items in the folder 'x'. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation stated that the following are the probable cause of your "[Invalid Token](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/practices#handling_errors_revoked_or_invalid_tokens)" error:

> Google Drive apps should account for the API returning an HTTP 401 or
>   HTTP 403 response when calling the Drive API. These errors could
>   indicate any of:
>
> - Token expiry.
> - Token revocation. This would cause both the access token and the refresh token to stop working.
> - Token not authorized for needed scopes.
> - Request not authorized correctly with OAuth 2.0 protocol.
>
> Token expiry can be handled by refreshing the credentials. If that
>   call fails with an "Invalid Credentials" error, the issue is probably
>   that the user has revoked access. For revoked access and all issues
>   other than token expiry, the best remedy is to redirect the user
>   through the OAuth dialog to re-grant access.

Then, you can check out [this link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list) for the implementation of `Files: list` method for you to be guided accordingly.

To enjoy more the benefit of the Good Drive API, you can [migrate](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/migration) to Drive API v3.

> The differences between Drive API v3 and v2 are mainly changes to
>   field names and removal of duplicate functionality.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question. I have scoured the documentation and found no example or even a paragraph mentioning 'nextpagetoken' with batch requests.